# What is the etymology of "Tarim" as in "Tarim Basin" and does it relate to Tocharian?

Tags: etymology, tocharian

I was trying to obtain a proper etymology for the name "Tarim" and found it rather difficult. The [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tar%C4%B1m#Turkish) page only lists the modern Turkish word tarım meaning agriculture, so was the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarim_River#Etymology) page that briefly describes the meaning of the word without providing any citations:

> The word tarim is used to designate the bank of a river that flows
>   into a lake or that is not able to be differentiated from the sands of
>   a desert.

So I turned my attention to the Turkish word tarım. The Wiktionary page links its origin to Old Turkic *tarı-*, which it provides with two meanings: "to sow" and "river delta". I was able to confirm the first meaning on [StarLing](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Calt%5Cturcet&first=1&off=&text_proto=*TAr%C9%A8-&method_proto=substring&ic_proto=on&text_meaning=&method_meaning=substring&ic_meaning=on&text_rusmean=&method_rusmean=substring&ic_rusmean=on&text_atu=&method_atu=substring&ic_atu=on&text_krh=&method_krh=substring&ic_krh=on&text_trk=&method_trk=substring&ic_trk=on&text_tat=&method_tat=substring&ic_tat=on&text_chg=&method_chg=substring&ic_chg=on&text_uzb=&method_uzb=substring&ic_uzb=on&text_uig=&method_uig=substring&ic_uig=on&text_sjg=&method_sjg=substring&ic_sjg=on&text_azb=&method_azb=substring&ic_azb=on&text_trm=&method_trm=substring&ic_trm=on&text_hak=&method_hak=substring&ic_hak=on&text_shr=&method_shr=substring&ic_shr=on&text_alt=&method_alt=substring&ic_alt=on&text_khal=&method_khal=substring&ic_khal=on&text_chv=&method_chv=substring&ic_chv=on&text_jak=&method_jak=substring&ic_jak=on&text_dolg=&method_dolg=substring&ic_dolg=on&text_tuv=&method_tuv=substring&ic_tuv=on&text_tof=&method_tof=substring&ic_tof=on&text_krg=&method_krg=substring&ic_krg=on&text_kaz=&method_kaz=substring&ic_kaz=on&text_nogx=&method_nogx=substring&ic_nogx=on&text_bas=&method_bas=substring&ic_bas=on&text_blkx=&method_blkx=substring&ic_blkx=on&text_gagx=&method_gagx=substring&ic_gagx=on&text_krmx=&method_krmx=substring&ic_krmx=on&text_klpx=&method_klpx=substring&ic_klpx=on&text_sal=&method_sal=substring&ic_sal=on&text_qum=&method_qum=substring&ic_qum=on&text_reference=&method_reference=substring&ic_reference=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=proto&ic_any=on), which lists the Proto-Turkic root *TArɨ- meaning "to cultivate (ground)". However, I was not able to find a reference validating the second meaning, which I suspect to be a more likely candidate if it's indeed etymologically connected to Tarim River/Basin.

In the meantime I decided to look for possible connections in Tocharian, knowing that the Tocharians themselves were long-time inhabitants of this region. I noticed the Tocharian word for "road, path, way", ytār in Tocharian A and ytārye in Tocharian B, which seem to be at least superficially similar to "Tarim" to some extent. Obviously I do not have the knowledge to draw any conclusions, but I am very curious about whether there was indeed a connection.

To sum it up, my question is two-fold:

1. What is the etymology of the word "Tarim"?
2. Does the word has any connections with Tocharian?

Comment: It seems that the name "Tarim basin" is very recent. Apparently, neither the Chinese nor the Uyghur used to call the area with such a name. When did this name start to be used? I think you should first settle this issue before understanding its origin?

Comment: The basin is obviously named after the river Tarim flowing through it. I could not find any reference on the etymology of the name of the river.

Comment: I think you have a valid point. The fact is that I have not been able to find any credible sources detailing the use of this name. It may be because that I am not currently able to acquire sources in Chinese, Uyghur, Tajik, and other related languages. I might ask this question on History:SE later.

Answer (score -4):

Guess if I came here, was asking the same question...
It could well be (proto-)Turskish (Sumerian ?), but I guess it has something to do with Scythian ("arima", one), Arimphaei and Arimaspi (sadly, all those are still a mystery).
The only thing we can say for sure is that this name is very old.

Comment: there is no serious suggestion that Sumerian is a Turkic language. The closest it gets is some claims that it may be Nostratic (itself highly controversial and generally considered unprovable), a putative macro-family that includes Turkic, but note that these proposals still do not generally assume any particularly close connection between Sumerian and Turkic